# After checkout to another branch and use git pull,Git merge files from previous branch

Tags: git, jenkins, repo

I have a following code in Jenkins which help me making a patch

```
git -C $PROJECT fetch
strTmp=$(git -C $PROJECT diff origin/$BRANCH..origin/master --name-only)
echo "strTmp = $strTmp"

if [ -n "$strTmp" ]; then
                
git -C $PROJECT reset --hard
git -C $PROJECT checkout $BRANCH
git -C $PROJECT pull
```

But from time to time i see what previous branch was merged in my local branch

```
HEAD is now at dac33 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into release/DEV-11111
branch 'release/DEV-19999' set up to track 'origin/release/DEV-19999'.
Switched to a new branch 'release/DEV-19999'
Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.
 CHK_CL_IP   | 28 ++++++++++++++++
 RED_IP | 29 +++++++++++++++++
 CR_P_IP | 46 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 IP | 29 +++++++++++++++++
 4 files changed, 132 insertions(+)
 CHK_CL_IP
 RED_IP
 CR_P_IP
 IP
```

Above files a merged from release/DEV-11111 and it's merged when git pull command are executed.
But why?
I was switched to another branch, why files from DEV-11111 are merged into my current branch?

I expected to only files from branch which we switched to are updated from remote

Comment: `git pull` literally means *fetch and merge*, except when you program it to mean *fetch and rebase* instead. If you want to use a commit as is, don't use `git pull`.

Comment: Hello @torek. Thank you very much for the answer. But if want to update my local repo and branch what i need to use? Is git fetch enough? I have a program which made a patch using local repo, so i need local branch is in sync with remote

Comment: Normally, you would use `git fetch` and `git checkout` (or `git switch`) here, and that's all. For build systems like Jenkins, though, there are numerous additional alternatives. Git doesn't prescribe any particular one.

Comment: @torek unfortunately it's doesn't work. I remove git -C $PROJECT pull from script and another branch not updated - "Your branch is behind 'origin/release/DEV-20000' by 4 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)"

Comment: As I said, in non-Jenkins code you'd normally use `git fetch` followed by `git checkout` or `git switch` (not by `git merge`, hence not the shortened `git pull`). You can't just remove the `git pull` step and stop though! You *must* replace it with whatever it is that you actually need. Because you're using Jenkins, there may be some Jenkins-specific replacement (I hate Jenkins in general though and hence don't know that much about it, as I have avoided getting deep into its weeds).

Comment: @torek. I modify git pull command to git pull origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) which allow me to pull only current branch. Thanks again for your answer

Comment: No, that's still wrong. *Stop using `git pull` entirely!* Use `git fetch` followed by `git switch` or `git checkout`.

Comment: @torek i can't use git pull because of reason i mentioned before -"Your branch is behind 'origin/release/DEV-20000' by 4 commits, and can be fast-forwarded. (use "git pull" to update your local branch)" . And i can't figure it out which command i need to use to replace git pull